# How to check if a domain has a ssl certificate in python?

Tags: python, ssl, web, dns, certificate

So, I have a problem and 2 hours of research haven't helped.

I want to write a method that will return me a Boolean if a web-domain(e.g. "google.com", without http/s) has an ssl-certificate.

I have a big csv of domain names, which I need to process and check if the domains have a ssl-certificate, is there a method maybe in pythons ssl module?

Thank you for your help, TomiiPomii.

Comment: Is this the one? https://pypi.org/project/sslchecker/

Comment: Also, it is a bit different thing to check if SSL certificate exists and if a *valid* SSL certificate exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using module `ssl` you can call `ssl.get_server_certificate((host, port))` to retrieve SSL of specified host in PEM format. You will then have to parse the PEM file to actually retrieve the certificate values, but if you only care about the website having or not having it, simply check the return value.

Comment: Thank you! I checked wether an error occured or not, and made my boolean based on that.

Comment: I didn't check whether no server certificate meant a specific return value or exception raising, glad you solved anyways.